# Finding Subgraph in a Graph

Tags: graph, pattern-matching, graph-algorithm, subgraph

I have a graph shown here. Just to node that nodes B_0, B_1, belong to node of type B, C_0, C_1. C_2, C_3 belong to node of type C and so on. 
Now, I want to find multiple subgraphs, which could satify criteria like defined by this example -

Criteria -

1. subgraph contains 1 node of type A, 1 node of type B, 1 node of type C, one node of type D.
2. subgraph has one edge from node of type A to one node of type B, one edge connecting type B and type C and one node connecting type C and type D.
3. subgraph contains one edge from type A going out of subgraph to type B node, one edge
   from type B to type C node outside, one edge from type D to type E outside.

Now this description should give result as -

1. subgraph :: A_0, B_0, C_1, D_1
2. subgraph :: A_0, B_0, C_0, D_0
3. subgraph :: A_0, B_1, C_2, D_2
4. subgraph :: A_0, B_1, C_3, D_3

I want to know, if there is any algorithm, by which I can find such sub-graphs?
I tried to figure out an algorithm by making all possible combinations. However, this would be exponential to number of nodes in subgraph. Thus, I want to know if there exists an efficient way to calculate it. Or if there exists a problem of similar nature in Graph Theory?

[image: Graph]

Comment: Looks like [partially ordered set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set). If it is a case than DFS works.

Answer (score 3):

You can start by visiting all nodes of type A. For each A node, look at all nodes connected to it which are of type B. From there look all nodes of type C and so on, keeping track of the nodes you've visited from the last A node. Then whenever you reach a subnode that completes the criteria of your search, you add all the list of nodes from the A node until the point where you are. Essentially you're doing a depth-first search where you keep traversing into the graph as long as a node meets the criteria of what should follow and backtrack whenever there's no more valid nodes (ie. which would produce a valid subgraph) going out from your current node.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. What I think is, it looks like a DFS problem. but supposed I had to choose like 2C, 3D and 2E, would it still be DFS-like problem? Because it should generate many subgraphs like `C_0,C_1,D_0,D_1,D_2,E_0,E_1` being one of the solutions. we can imagine the others.